# Add link to namespace'd route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Let's start off with some code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :mpd do
    get 'help' #==> get "mpd/help", as: :mpd_help
    get 'status'
    post 'start'
    post 'stop'
    post 'next'
    post 'previous'
    post 'pause'
    post 'update'
    # post 'play_song/:id', to: 'mpd#play_song'
  end
  # For some reason this path must not be in the namespace?!
  post '/mpd/play_song/:id', to: 'mpd#play_song', as: 'mpd_play_song'



  root 'static#home'

  #match '*path' => 'static#home', via: [:get, :post]
end
```

Why do I have to specify the mpd_play_song_path outside of my namespace?
It uses the same controller and a function within, however, I receive the following error upon putting it within the namespace:

```
undefined method `mpd_play_song_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f2b30f7fd20>:0x007f2b30f7eb50>
```

And this is the line within my view:

```
= link_to("Play", mpd_play_song_path(song[:id])
```

I find this fairly strange and do not see any reason besides the passed `id` why it shouldn't work.

Hit me up if you need more code.
Thanks in advance,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Namespace**

Having a namespace does not denote the controller your routes will assume.

A namespace is basically a folder within which you'll place controllers.
You still have to use the [`resources` directive](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) and set the controller actions:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :mdp do
   resources :controller do
      collection do
        get :help #-> url.com/mdp/controller/help
      end
   end
end
```

It seems to me that you're wanting to use the `mdp` controller, which means you'd set up your routes as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :mdp do
   get :help, action: :show, type: :help
   get :status, action: :show, type: :status
   ...
end
```

A more succinct way will be to use [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :mdp, except: :show do
   get :id, to: :show, constraints: ActionsConstraints 
end

#lib/actions_constraints.rb
class NewUserConstraint
   def self.matches?(request)
     actions = %i(help status)
     actions.include? request.query_parameters['id']
   end
end
```